# Euclidean Geometry: Diagonals of Cyclic Hexagon

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Convex Hexagon $ABCDEF$ is cyclic. Prove that its three main diagonals $AD$, $BE$ and $CF$ are concurrent iff:

$$|AB| \cdot |CD| \cdot |EF|=|BC| \cdot |DE| \cdot |FA|$$

This seems like it might have something to do with Ptolemy's Theorem about Cyclic quadrilaterals. But I've got no idea how to apply it.

Hints would be  greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is the trigonometric form of Ceva's theorem in a rather helpless disguise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Label the generic convex cyclic hexagon as shown, with $P$, $Q$, $R$ the (not-necessarily-distinct) points where pairs of diagonals meet. Note that we take $\triangle PQR$ to "point toward" segments $AB$, $CD$, and $EF$.

[image: Cyclic Hexagon]

Consider $\triangle PAB$ and $\triangle PED$. Here, $\angle A$ and $\angle E$ subtend the same arc, $\stackrel{\frown}{BD}$, and are therefore congruent; also, $\angle B \cong \angle D$. Thus, $\triangle PAB \sim \triangle PED$, and (because of how $\triangle PQR$ "points"), we can write:

$$\frac{a}{e+q} = \frac{b}{d+r} = \frac{|AB|}{|DE|}$$

with $q$ and $r$ (and, below, $p$) non-negative. Likewise, 
$$
\frac{c}{a+r} = \frac{d}{f+p} = \frac{|CD|}{|FA|} \qquad\qquad
\frac{e}{c+p} = \frac{f}{b+q} = \frac{|EF|}{|BC|}
$$
so that
$$\frac{|AB|^2}{|DE|^2}\cdot\frac{|CD|^2}{|FA|^2}\cdot\frac{|EF|^2}{|BC|^2} =
\frac{a}{a+r} \cdot \frac{b}{b+q} \cdot \frac{c}{c+p} \cdot \frac{d}{d+r} \cdot \frac{e}{e+q} \cdot \frac{f}{f+p}$$

which equals $1$ if and only if $p=q=r=0$.

Therefore, $|AB|\cdot|CD|\cdot|EF| = |DE|\cdot|FA|\cdot|BC|$ if and only if the diagonals concur. $\square$

Comment: Hmmm ... Having used "concur" as the active formulation of "are concurrent", I'm tempted to replace "are congruent" with "congrue". Merriam-Webster.com informs me that the term is obsolete, but perhaps we could bring it back.

Comment: Really really neat. Thanks for avoiding Ptolemy's Theorem.

Comment: You may like Cartensen's proof more than your trignometric one, but I like this proof more than Cartensen's. :)

Comment: @EuYu: I like Cartensen's proof more than my *original* attempt, which was rather inartful. I actually like my final version very much. :)  Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 5):

[image: I send my dolution to the following problem:Convex Hexagon ABCDEF is cyclic. Prove that its three main diagonals AD, BE and CF are concurrent iff:|AB|⋅|CD|⋅|EF|=|BC|⋅|DE|⋅|FA|Leonard Giugiuc]

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 4):

The proof is given in Jens Cartensen's ["About Hexagons"](http://ms.appliedprobability.org/data/files/Abstracts%2033/33-2-5.pdf). For completeness I will reproduce it here.

[image: hexagons]

Suppose that the diagonals intersect at $O$. Then $\triangle ABO$ and $\triangle EDO$ are similar with
$$\frac{AB}{DE} = \frac{AO}{EO}$$
Similarly, the other two pairs of similar triangles gives
$$\frac{CD}{FA}=\frac{CO}{AO},\ \ \ \ \frac{EF}{BC}=\frac{EO}{CO}$$
Multiplied together, these give the desired product.

Conversely, suppose the product holds, i.e.
$$ace = bdf$$ 
Let $BE$ and $AD$ intersect at $O$. Extend $CO$ to intersect the circle at $F_1$. From the previous discussion, we get
$$ace_1 = bdf_1$$
The two equalities so far provide
$$acef_1 = bdff_1 = acfe_1$$
which cancel to provide
$$ef_1 = fe_1$$
From Ptolemy's theorem on Cyclic quadrilaterals on $AEFF_1$ we get
$$ef_1 = e_1f + FF_1\cdot AE \implies FF_1 \cdot AE = 0 \implies FF_1 = 0$$
so that $CF$ also passes through $O$ as required. $\square$

Answer (score 2):

Let us prove one direction.

Assume that $AD, BE, CF$ are concurrent at a point $P$. Consider $\triangle BFD$. From Trig Ceva, we have $$\frac{\sin \angle FDA}{\sin \angle ADB} \cdot \frac{\sin \angle DBE}{\sin \angle EBF} \cdot \frac{\sin \angle BFC}{\sin \angle CFD} = 1$$

Let the circumradius be $R$. From Law of Sines, 
\begin{align*}
AB &=  2R\sin \angle ADB \\
AF & = 2R \sin \angle ADF \\
FE & = 2R \sin \angle FBE \\
ED & = 2R \sin \angle DBE \\
CD & = 2R \sin \angle CFD \\
BC & = 2R \sin \angle BFC \\
\end{align*}
Indeed, 
$AB \cdot CD \cdot EF = BC \cdot DE \cdot AF$, holds true because it is just the equation derived from Trig Ceva.

Since the steps are reversible, we have other proven the other direction, as desired.